# How do I check or count post "draft" status and display bubble next to the menu in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, customization, wp-admin

So thanks to [rudrastyh](https://rudrastyh.com/wordpress/notification-counter-bubbles.html) I was able to get the main part of the code that will enable the notification bubbles but don't have any way yet of checking and counting the Testimonials in `draft` status only (and displaying count in the bubble) I am very green at php and if someone can provide an answer would be so grateful - thanks in advance!

```
// ADD BUBBLES TO ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH

add_action( 'admin_menu', function() {

    global $menu;

    $count = 5;

    $menu_item = wp_list_filter(
        $menu,
        array( 2 => 'edit.php?post_type=testimonials' ) // 2 is the position of an array item which contains URL, it will always be 2!
    );

    if ( ! empty( $menu_item )  ) {
        $menu_item_position = key( $menu_item ); // get the array key (position) of the element
        $menu[ $menu_item_position ][0] .= ' <span class="awaiting-mod">' . $count . '</span>';
    }

});
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', function() {

    global $menu;

    //$count = 5;
    $args = array(
        'numberposts'   => -1,
        'post_type'     => 'testimonials',
        'fields' => 'ids',
        'no_found_rows' => true,
        'post_status'   => array( 'draft' ),

    );
    $count_drafts = count( get_posts( $args ) ); 
    if($count_drafts > 0) {
  
    $menu_item = wp_list_filter(
        $menu,
        array( 2 => 'edit.php?post_type=testimonials' ) // 2 is the position of an array item which contains URL, it will always be 2!
    );

    if ( ! empty( $menu_item )  ) {
        $menu_item_position = key( $menu_item ); // get the array key (position) of the element
        $menu[ $menu_item_position ][0] .= ' <span class="awaiting-mod">' . $count_drafts . '</span>';
    }
    }
});
```

Important detail, we use in the query

```
'fields' => 'ids',
'no_found_rows' => true,
```

because we only need to calculate the count, its significantly reduces the load on the database and speeds up the query

Comment: that works perfectly - except for it will show a '0' if no posts are in draft status, I would not want any badge to show at all if that's the case. https://prnt.sc/1tl5ytn

Comment: I update code, we use if($count_drafts > 0)  to avoid 0

Comment: And it works perfectly - Thank-you very much!!